# Get value by family in HBase

Tags: java, hadoop, hbase

Row:

```
Key, Family:Qualifier, Value
Key, Family1:Qualifier, Value
Key, Family2:Qualifier, Value
Key, FamilyN:Qualifier, Value
```

In the Java HBase API we can scan a table row by row and then get a `FamilyMap` for each row.

Is there any option to get all the row for a specific `family` without knowing the `qualifier`?

If yes, is there a difference in term of performance between: get value by key or get value by family ?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the scanner on a specific family like this. Getting a scanner on a specific column family returns only that family data as part of the result. What this means is that the qualifier and values which are part of that family are availabe as part of the result.

```
HTable table = new HTable(HBaseConfiguration.create(), "tablename");
Scan scan = new scan();
scan.setCaching(NUMBER_OF_ROWS_TO_CACHE);
//If you want to get data for all families then do not add any family.
scan.addFamily(Bytes.toBytes("columnFamilyName"));
ResultScanner scanner = table.getScanner(scan);
```

If you do not add any family to the `scan` object created above then you get data of all the column families. Now you can scan the table by iterating like this

```
for (Result result = scanner.next(); (result != null); result = scanner.next()) {
    //If you want a family specific data
    NavigableMap familyMap = result.getFamilyMap(Bytes.toBytes("familyname"));
    //if you want to get the entire row 
    Get get = new Get(result.getRow());
    Result entireRow = table.get(get); 

}
```

As for the performance when you get all the row data it will be comparatively slow because all data for all the column families for a specific row is fetched. So, unless you want all of your families do not get the entire row.

Comment: Strange... you do table.get(get); in order to get a result by you already have the result in your loop... (Result result = scanner.next() and, does it mean that we can't get a row by a family and without a key?

Comment: @JohnJohnGa `table.get(get)` gets the entire row containing data of all column families. Let me edit the answer to make it more clear.

Comment: Yes, you are right. You cannot get a specific row by family. Family is part of the table schema. To get a specific row, you have to get the row using the `rowkey` which is what the `table.get(get)` does.